# How to create Scala SBT multi independent project

Tags: scala, sbt, project-structure

I am trying to create sbt multi independent project.

I want my project structure some thing like

My Scala and sbt version is 2.12.2 and 1.5.5 respectively.

```
sbt-multi-project-example/
    common/
      project
      src/
        main/
        test/
      target/
      build.sbt
    multi1/
      project
      src/
        main/
        test/
      target/
      build.sbt
    multi2/
      project
      src/
        main/
        test/
      target/
      build.sbt
    project/
      build.properties
      plugins.sbt
    build.sbt
```

so I referred some github repo:

https://github.com/pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example (project build is success but i want `build.sbt` in each individual modules.)

how can I create above project structure and basic idea is `common` project contains common methods and class.
`multi1`(Independent project) uses common methods and it has its own methods and classes.

`multi2`(Independent project) uses common methods and it has its own methods and classes.

what are the changes I need to change in all `build.sbt` in order to achieve above scenario.

Comment: Can you explain why you want a `build.sbt` in each project?

Comment: Because after that i want to create dependency of each module for example if anyone want to use only module 2 then just add dependency of module 2 in thair project

Comment: You can refer this see how they create each module and each module has its own pom.xml here we have build.sbt https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/core and https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/graphx

Comment: Maven need a pom in each module, SBT does not. But SBT will still publish independent artifacts for each module and actually will publish one POM per module. Unless you clarify, there's no reason to want one SBT file per module.

Comment: Ok you mean with only one SBT I can achive above scenario right? Then its ok I can go ahead without SBT file in each module. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basic structure. As mentioned in the comments this can create a separate publishable artefact for each project so no need for a separate `build.sbt`

```
lazy val all = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(common, multi1, multi2)

lazy val common =
  project
    .in(file("common"))
    .settings(
      name := "common",
      version := "0.1",
      // other project settings
    )

lazy val multi1 =
  project
    .in(file("multi1"))
    .settings(
      name := "multi1",
      version := "0.1",
    )
    .dependsOn(common)
```

---